# DroneKit Joystick Override

Tags: joystick, dronekit-python, dronekit, mavlink

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use DroneKit to override joystick control when it's enabled in Mission Planner.  In my scenario if I enable joystick in Mission Planner and forcibly close Mission Planner, the joystick still maintains control over the UAV.  Knowing that I'm still able to use switches on my RC transmitter, I'd like to be able to flip a switch and have joystick mode disabled so that the RC then has full control of the UAV again.

Would appreciate any pointers or examples if they already exist.  I'm familiar with DroneKit and how to monitor RC channels, so looking more for what command I need to send to disable joystick mode.

Many thanks